# Mongodb compound index - also built in _id sort?

Tags: mongodb, compound-index

I have a compound index

```
{ userID:1, connectionStatus: 1, userTargetLastName: 1})
```

I want to support two queries:

```
UserConnection.find( { $and : [ { userID : req.decoded.id }, { connectionStatus : 'accepted' } ] })
                .sort({'_id': -1}).exec()
```

and

```
UserConnection.find( { $and : [ { userID : req.decoded.id }, { connectionStatus : 'accepted' } ] })
                .sort({'userTargetLastName': 1}).exec()
```

I am confused whether I need a second compound index to sort by _id or whether that is "built in" to my compound index? (as per the mongodb docs, my compound index should also support userID:1, connectionStatus:1 queries (but in what orders can I sort them? By _id?). So do I need to add another compound index on either _id or created?

```
 { userID:1, connectionStatus: 1, created: -1})
```

Answer (score 1):

You are only querying on `userID` and `connectionStatus`, so your compound index does not need to include `userTargetLastName`.  The sort gets done on the results of the query, and its not essential to have an index on the sort field, so it isn't important to include `_id` in the index.

The best way to check on the index use is to use the `explain()` function with your query.  This will tell you a lot about which index is being used, and how efficient it is (number of documents scanned etc).

Comment: thank you, I should have said I want to limit my queries to 10. There can be say 200 results for userID with a certain connectionStatus. I want 10 sorted either by userTargetLastName or _id (or created).

Comment: also, thanks on the "explain()" - I will use it now to check whether things are working as I want

Comment: You can also use explain("executionStats") and explain("allPlansExecution") to optimize your query. See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/